# How to implement button click functionality in Pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

After a user loses in my game, I want to display a game-over screen that has a restart button/restart image that restarts the game when the user clicks on it with his/her mouse.

I don't know how to implement this mouse click functionality in my code.

For my game, I have a `Game()` class, with the methods, `processEvents()`, `runLogic()` and `displayFrame()`. I run these methods in the `while` loop of `main()`.

```
# loop inside of main()
# pygame, display surface - called screen, already initialized
while not gameExit:
    gameExit = game.processEvents()
    game.runLogic()
    game.displayFrame(screen, background)
```

In the `__init__()` method of the `Game()` class, I have an attribute `self.gameOver = False`. When `self.gameOver` is becomes `True`, the `runLogic()` function does not run, but instead `displayFrame()` calls a function, `gameOver(display)` that displays the game-over screen.

```
def displayFrame(self, display, background):

    if self.gameOver:
        gameOver(display)

    if not self.gameOver:
        display.blit(background, (0, 0))
        self.allsprites.update()
        self.allsprites.draw(display)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

The `gameOver(display)` function displays a restart button.

```
def gameOver(display):
    # loadImage returns (image, image.get_rect())
    restartImage = utility.loadImage("restart.png")
    display.blit(restartImage[0], (320, 250))
```

I want to make it such that when the user clicks this `restartImage`, the game restarts.

I know that I'll have to handle mouseclick in the `processEvents()` function.

```
def processEvents(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # need to use collidepointrect function
            # don't know how to implement!
    return False
```

Ideally, I will have a function `isButtonClicked` that goes something like this

```
def isButtonClicked(mousepos, button):
    return button.collidepoint(mousepos)
```

And in the `processEvents` function, I just do

```
if self.isButtonClicked(pos, restartImage[1]):
    # restart the game 
    self.__init__()
```

HOWEVER, I cannot directly pass in `restartImage` as it has been created in `gameOver(display)`. So, I'm not sure how to structure my code so that `processEvents` can handle a mouseclick to the image/button I created in another function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Sorry if my explanation is a bit convoluted. I felt it was necessary to explain my code structure, as my question is more about how to logically write my code than what methods to use.

Comment: don't run `self.__init__()` - create function `reset_data()` which set all values at start and use it in `__init__()` and when you what to restart game.

Comment: `gameOver` is strange - it is executed thousends times in second and you load image thounsends times. Can't you load image only once ?

Comment: maybe you should split class `Game()` into two classes `Game` and `GameOver` with own functions `processEvents`, `runLogic`  and `displayFrame` so they have more control on elements in functions - like this http://imgur.com/MT7tZ4s. Or you should replace class in variable `game` to use different `processEvents`, `runLogic`  and `displayFrame` when game is over.